# T-SQL to list all the user mappings with database roles/permissions for a User

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, permissions

I am looking for a t-sql script which can list the databases and and the respective roles/privileges mapped for a particular user. Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Regards
Mohammed

Comment: Have you tried any solution? This looks a bit like homework you request others to do. Have you tried to build a query using [security catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178542.aspx)?

Comment: I am a DBA not a developer to break my head on coding ;-) If you wanna help, then please help me out! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Within each database, you should be able to do something like:

```
execute as login = 'SomeLogin';

select *
from sys.database_principals
where IS_MEMBER(name) = 1;

revert;
```

And you should be able to look in `sys.database_permissions` to see what has been gratned to each database_principal.